# Convert a string into multiple JSON objects

Tags: python

I have a below string multiple lines. For each line, I want to split string and add this to a JSON output file. I had done this using `string.gettext().split` and a regular expression. However I am not sure this is the best way to do it.

**Input file :**

```
Server:prod01
Available memory: 20480      Disk:200     CPU:4
Used memory:12438              Disk:120     CPU:3
Unused memory:8042            Disk:80       CPU:1
Server:prod02
Available memory: 40960      Disk:500     CPU:8
Used memory:20888              Disk:320     CPU:3
Unused memory:20072          Disk:180    CPU:5
```

**Expected output JSON:**

```
{"prod01_available_memory":20480}
{"prod01_used_memory":12438}
{"prod01_unused_memory":8042}
{"prod01_available_disk":200}
{"prod01_used_disk":120}
{"prod01_unused_disk":80}
{"prod01_available_cpu":4}
{"prod01_used_cpu":3}
{"prod01_unused_cpu":1}
{"prod02_available_memory":40960}
{"prod02_used_memory":20888}
{"prod02_unused_memory":20072"}
{"prod02_available_disk":500"}
{"prod02_used_disk":380}
{"prod02_unused_disk":120}
{"prod02_available_cpu":8}
{"prod02_used_cpu":3}
{"prod02_unused_cpu":5}
```

Thanks,
Rinku

Below is my code -

```
def tsplit(string, *delimiters):
    pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    return re.split(pattern, string)


prelist = pre.get_text().splitlines()
server_name = re.split('server|:',prelist[0])[2].strip()
if server_name == 'prod01':
    #print prelist[1]
    prod01_memory_actv = int(re.split('Activated memory|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[1])[2])
    prod01_Disk_actv = int(re.split('Activated memory|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[1])[4])
    prod01_CPU_actv = int(re.split('Activated memory|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[1])[6])
    #print prelist[2]
    prod01_memory_cons = int(re.split('memory consumed|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[2])[2])
    prod01_Disk_cons = int(re.split('memory consumed|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[2])[4])
    prod01_CPU_cons = int(re.split('memory consumed|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[2])[6])
    #print prelist[4]
    prod01_memory_unused = int(re.split('memory unused|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[4])[2])
    prod01_Disk_unused = int(re.split('memory unused|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[4])[4])
    prod01_CPU_unused = int(re.split('memory unused|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[4])[6])
elif server_name == 'prod02':
    #print prelist[1]
    prod02memory_actv = int(re.split('Activated memory|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[1])[2])
    prod02Disk_actv = int(re.split('Activated memory|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[1])[4])
    prod02CPU_actv = int(re.split('Activated memory|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[1])[6])
    #print prelist[2]
    prod02memory_cons = int(re.split('memory consumed|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[2])[2])
    prod02Disk_cons = int(re.split('memory consumed|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[2])[4])
    prod02CPU_cons = int(re.split('memory consumed|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[2])[6])
    #print prelist[4]
    prod02memory_unused = int(re.split('memory unused|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[4])[2])
    prod02Disk_unused = int(re.split('memory unused|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[4])[4])
    prod02CPU_unused = int(re.split('memory unused|:|Disk|:|CPU|:',prelist[4])[6])
else
    #assign all varaiables 0

.....

    proc_item["logtime"] = str(t1)
    proc_item["prod01_memory_actv"] = prod01_memory_actv
    proc_item["prod01_Disk_actv"] = prod01_Disk_actv
    proc_item["prod01_CPU_actv"] = prod01_CPU_actv
    ......
    #for all otehr variables...

    proc_data.append(proc_item)
    with open("./proc_"+ str(date.today()) + ".txt", 'a+') as f:
            json.dump(proc_data, f)
            f.write("\n")
```

I have some basic knowledge on python.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  Show your code, and current vs. expected output.  Note that the output you have displayed is not valid JSON...it is [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/).

Comment: Added the code I have used. it works fine.
But surely this is probably not the smart code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with dict then just dump over json.(in your case i dont think its valid json but its needs so as per your request i have dump dict over json) i havn't validates keys, i am assuming you get dictionary data correct.

```
d = { 'Server':'prod01', 
      'Available memory': 20480,
      'Disk':200,
      'CPU':4}

import json

s = json.dumps({str(d['Server']+"_"+key).replace(' ','_'):value for key,value in d.items()})
print(json.loads(s))

>>> {'prod01_Server': 'prod01', 'prod01_Available memory': 20480, 'prod01_Disk': 200, 'prod01_CPU': 4}
```

Comment: please mark as answer, so it will be useful for others

Comment: @Rinku Not too sure how this answer satisfy your requirements since both the input and the output in this answer differ quite significantly from those in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
- Just using string array indices 

    hostmtrcs = "Server:prod01 Available memory:20480 Disk:200 CPU:4 Used memory:12438 Disk:120 CPU:3 Unused memory:8042 " \
                "Disk:80 CPU:1 Server:prod02 Available memory: 40960 Disk:500 CPU:8 Used memory:20888 Disk:320 CPU:3 Unused " \
                "memory:20072 Disk:180 CPU:5 "

datasplt = hostmtrcs.split(":")
hstname = ''
attrkey = ''
attrvalue = ''

for word in range(0, datasplt.__len__()):

    if not datasplt[word].__contains__("Server"):
        elmnt = datasplt[word].split(" ")
        if datasplt[word].__contains__('prod'):
            hstname = elmnt[0].lower()
        if elmnt.__len__() == 3:
            attrkey = elmnt[1].lower() + "_" + elmnt[2].lower()  # attrkey
        else:
            attrkey = elmnt[1]

        # retreive the value from the next element in the 1st attry datasplit

        if word != datasplt.__len__() - 1:
            nxtelmnt = datasplt[word + 1].split(" ")
            attrvalue = nxtelmnt[0]  # sattrvalue frm next element
        finalfrmt = '{' + '"' +hstname + "_" + attrkey + '"' + ":" + attrvalue + '}'
        print(finalfrmt)
```

Comment: Answer would be better with more explanation for future users.

Comment: @CGritton, sure, basically the idea is, first split the given the array by ":" as delimiter. use the splitted string and split again using the " ". Derive the hostname, attribute key and then fetch the attribute value by looking into the next element in the array (Which was by split ":")

Answer (score 0):

You should split the input text, section by section, according to what you're looking for.

```
data = '''Server:prod01
Available memory: 20480      Disk:200     CPU:4
Used memory:12438              Disk:120     CPU:3
Unused memory:8042            Disk:80       CPU:1
Server:prod02
Available memory: 40960      Disk:500     CPU:8
Used memory:20888              Disk:320     CPU:3
Unused memory:20072          Disk:180    CPU:5'''

import re
import json
print(json.dumps({'_'.join((s, l.split(' ', 1)[0], k)).lower(): int(v) for s, d in [i.split('\n', 1) for i in data.split('Server:') if i] for l in d.split('\n') for k, v in re.findall(r'(\w+):\s*(\d+)', l)}))
```

This outputs:

```
{"prod01_available_memory": 20480, "prod01_available_disk": 200, "prod01_available_cpu": 4, "prod01_used_memory": 12438, "prod01_used_disk": 120, "prod01_used_cpu": 3, "prod01_unused_memory": 8042, "prod01_unused_disk": 80, "prod01_unused_cpu": 1, "prod02_available_memory": 40960, "prod02_available_disk": 500, "prod02_available_cpu": 8, "prod02_used_memory": 20888, "prod02_used_disk": 320, "prod02_used_cpu": 3, "prod02_unused_memory": 20072, "prod02_unused_disk": 180, "prod02_unused_cpu": 5}
```